# Disable PayPal Digital Goods on Sandbox Account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

PayPal is [no longer offering new Digital Goods integrations](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/digital-goods/). I'd like to test a new Express Checkout integration I'm working on against a PayPal Sandbox account which does NOT have Digital Goods enabled. Yet, every new Sandbox account I create has [Digital Goods enabled by default](http://cspf.co/gAcw/Image%202016-05-12%20at%2011.24.41%20AM.png).

How can I **disable** Digital Goods on a Sandbox account?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no impact on your testing for Express Checkout.
As long as you didn't pass the parameters to determine the transaction type as Digital goods, PayPal will regard it as Physical goods transactions by default.

Comment: We are selling Digital Goods. Is there a way to sell Digital types w/out having Digital Goods enabled on the account (which is no longer available?) Basically I'm wondering, how to sell Digital recurring subscriptions via Express Checkout without having Digital Goods enabled on the account?